# Does the search in Stackexchange search comments as well, are they indexed by bots?

Tags: discussion, support

If someone enters a new question or uses the search function of StackExchange he/she gets suggestions of similar questions or results.

**Does this take comments on the question or one of the answers into account?**

**Are comments indexed by search engines (Google Bot etc.)?**

For example the question "[How do I keep my TorBrowserBundle current?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/318/how-do-i-keep-my-tor-browser-bundle-current)" is phrased very well. However I'd like users to find the question via "How to keep the TorBrowserBundle up-to-date?" (or similar) Would adding a comment on the question itself be suitable for that purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments are not searchable using our internal search; they're meant to be ephemeral chatter that is normally removed after the results of a brief conversation are moved into the parent post, so it doesn't make much sense for us to make them searchable.

There are, however, some comments that stick around because they have lasting value, but don't *really* belong in the post itself. For that, yes, you can use Google or other search engines if you've got an idea of what the comment contains. Just use the `site:` modifier (for Google) and you can probably turn them up.

The best thing to do in order to make content easy to discover is to make sure the title is as descriptive of the question as possible, and that the question is well explained. In our experience, Google and other search engines are quite good at connecting folks with the best subset of questions in search results. Tagging is also important here, as the system quite often incorporates the most heavily used tag attached to a question in the title.

For instances where you've got something where folks might search a number of ways, you'll probably end up with people asking duplicate questions because nothing turned up for them in their particular query. When this happens, just mark the question as a duplicate of the *best* version of it that you have, and it becomes a sort of 'stub' to lead people to a canonical answer on the topic.

In short, don't worry too much about SEO beyond clear titles - a feature of our engine is that it's *quite* good at getting that right.